# Changed domain for Django app, can't reach url

Tags: django, dns

I recently moved my website from django to an e-commerce platform. I would still like to use Django and Python for various web-tools so after pointing the website domain at the new host I added a subdomain of tools.domain.com. I then changed the "domain" collumn in the django_site table to the new subdomain "tools.domain.com" and restarted the app. I can get to my admin area and login but when I attempt to access the url of the tool as defined in urls.py i get a "Page unavailable" error. I haven't edited settings.py or url.py.

What am I missing in this process?

Comment: If `debug` is `False`, then you will have to add the new domain to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` the setting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I have my new subdomain in ALLOWED_HOSTS. Oddly I can reach /admin just fine, everything else is "page unavalable"